# None of the 3 bytes to integer examples work

Tags: java

**Background**

I am taking 8, 16, 24 or 32 bit audio data and converting them to integers, but BigInteger cannot be recycled and using it will waste lot of memory so I created this class to fix the memory consumption. And seems like ByteBuffer will do the job well, except if the input is 3 bytes long.

I have never done any bit or byte operations, so I am completely lost here.

**Issue**

None of the examples that I found on stackoverflow on *3 bytes to int* do not give the wanted result. Check the bytesToInt3 method.

**Question**

Is there something obvious that I am doing completely wrong?

Is the *return new BigInteger(byte[] data).intValue();* really the only solution to this?

**Code**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

class BytesToInt {

    // HELP
    private static int bytes3ToInt(byte[] data) {

        // none below seem to work, even if I swap first and last bytes
        // these examples are taken from stackoverflow

        //return (data[2] & 0xFF) | ((data[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((data[0] & 0x0F) << 16);
        //return ((data[2] & 0xF) << 16) | ((data[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (data[0] & 0xFF);
        //return ((data[2] << 28) >>> 12) | (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
        //return (data[0] & 255) << 16 | (data[1] & 255) << 8 | (data[2] & 255);
        return (data[2] & 255) << 16 | (data[1] & 255) << 8 | (data[0] & 255);

        // Only thing that works, but wastes memory
        //return new BigInteger(data).intValue();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Test with -666 example number
        byte[] negativeByteArray3 = new byte[] {(byte)0xff, (byte)0xfd, (byte)0x66};
        testWithData(negativeByteArray3);

    }

    private static void testWithData(byte[] data) {

        // Compare our converter to BigInteger
        // Which we know gives wanted result
        System.out.println("Converter  = " + bytes3ToInt(data));
        System.out.println("BigInteger = " + new BigInteger(data).intValue());
    }


}
```

**Output**

```
Converter  = 6749695
BigInteger = -666
```

full code here http://ideone.com/qu9Ulw

Comment: *"do not give the wanted result"* What result are you expecting and what are you getting? In short, edit question and show the *expected* and *actual* values.

Comment: [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is by default [`BIG_ENDIAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#BIG_ENDIAN), and you don't change that, but your `bytes3ToInt` is doing `LITTLE_ENDIAN`, so flip `data[2]` and `data[0]`. Read more about the difference on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your indices are wrong. It's not 2, 1, 0 but 0, 1, 2.

Secondly the problem is that the sign isn't being extended, so even though it would work for positive values, negative values show wrong.

If you don't mask the highest (of 24bits) byte, it will sign extend properly, filling the highest (of 32bits) byte with 0x00 for positive values or 0xFF for negative values.

```
return (data[0] << 16) | (data[1] & 255) << 8 | (data[2] & 255);
```

Comment: The purpose of `& 255` is to remove the sign, so wouldn't *not* doing that on the first byte retain the sign? `return data[0] << 16 | (data[1] & 255) << 8 | (data[2] & 255);`

Comment: @Andreas Oh yeah, of course. Jeez I don't know why I bother with bit fiddling in the evenings. :D

Comment: @Kayaman Edit the last data[0] to data[2] and we have correct solution! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @SHOTbyGUN Ah yes, there we go.